# Flutter stripe SDK custom form

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments, flutter-in-app-purchase

I need to add stripe to a flutter app where I can save a credit card with a custom form, but since I only found an unofficial sdk that provides a pre-built form ([stripe_payments](https://pub.dev/packages/stripe_payment)), is there a way to work with API requests without relying on an SDK?

Answer (score 2):

All SDKs are essentially just wrappers for Stripe's API. You can make those calls yourself using something like curl or fetch: https://stripe.com/docs/api?lang=curl

Bear in mind that some of those calls require a secret key and some can be done with a publishable key. You should never use a secret key on your client, only on your server.